# Service stops after restarting phone

Tags: android

I have a service running from an `AlarmManager` set to record sensor data at regular intervals.

I had a problem where opening the app would execute the service in it's `onCreate` every time the app was started/run. So I implemented the following to ensure it only runs at it's intervals:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service.class );
        AlarmManager scheduler = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //Boolean to see if alarm is already set:
        alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        //make pending intent to schedule
        PendingIntent scheduledIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if (runOnce == false){

            if (!alarmUp){
                Log.d("alarmUp", "= false");
                scheduler.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 900000, 900000, scheduledIntent);
            }
                runOnce = true;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();                         
                    editor.putBoolean(RUN_ONCE, runOnce);
                    editor.commit();            
        }               
        //Alarm Manager schedule Start Service:
        if (alarmUp){
            Log.d("alarmUp", "= true");
            // 15 min intervals = 900000
            //scheduler.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 900000, scheduledIntent);
            scheduler.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 900000, 900000, scheduledIntent);
        }
```

I introduced the `runOnce` boolean because the `getBroadcast` was either always running the service, or not starting it at all on a fresh install of the application. This was the solution, but causes a new problem - **after turning the device on and off, the service won't start again.**

How can I address this problem? I can either find another way to start the service without having it running too frequently, or implement a check for when the device was last turned off to reset the runOnce boolean?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I address this problem?

Reschedule your alarms after a reboot, using an `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver`, as is illustrated in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled). `AlarmManager` scheduled events do not survive a reboot, so you have to re-establish them yourself.

BTW, I would recommend replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `this` in your code shown above. Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know **why** you should be using `getApplicationContext()` in the specific situation.

Comment: The link you provided does not illustrate the rescheduling of an alarm after a reboot as you described

Comment: @SQLiteNoob: Sure it does. `PollReceiver` gets control at boot time and will call `scheduleAlarms()` to schedule the alarms.

Comment: So when `BOOT_COMPLETED` is registered in the manifest, the `BroadcastReceiver` then persists reboot to run its code (via `onReceive`, which is waiting for `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`)?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob: I am not quite certain what "persists reboot" means. When an Android device powers on, one of its tasks is to send the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` system broadcast. Apps holding the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission and with a `BroadcastReceiver` that is listening for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` in the manifest will receive this broadcast and can do something short, such as schedule alarms in `AlarmManager`.

Comment: It's all sorted. My first time ever needing a BroadcastReceiver - thanks for the help @CommonsWare.